# how to control servo motor using embedded c using simple code?

Tags: avr, avrdude, winavr

**i'm working on a school project "automatic railway system"
my project suppose to close the gate when the train coming to the station with a buzzer on with 90 sec count down display on 7-seg. and a led flashing.
 after the train leaving the station, the gate opens and the buzzer off  and the led off .
i tried to use a dc motor to open and close the gate but it didn't give me the accurate angle that i need to i try to use a servo motor .
so i need it to open the gate at position zero and close it at position 90 .
all the code i found on the internet they using PWM and timers which i didn't  take it in my course , so can anyone help me to do this with simple code ,please  ?**

*i'm using Atmega32 running at 16000000 HZ*

Comment: Servo motors require PWM to operate. You can use the built-in PWM, or you can use interrupts to turn the pin on and off at the correct rate yourself. Search the web or Stack Overflow for example code and tutorials. Don't ask such a broad question here.

Comment: Thanks ,, I will try to understand pwm and using it in my project

Answer (score 1):

Its depend on your analog servo (which is controlled by PWM) frequency specification. After you learn about the servo specification, you can set your PWM using build-in features on cvavr compiler, or you can do some research about PWM registers.
Here is some example of PWM setup

```
//using OC0 (B.3)
DDRB.3 = 1; //set B.3 as output
TCCR0=0b0111 0001;
TCNT0=0; //set to Phase Correct PWM mode, no prescaler, and inverted output

//to assign a value to your PWM
OCR0 = 127 //50% duty cycle since it was 8 bit
```